# mysqli query to check if old password inputted matches with database

Tags: php, mysqli

what is the correct query to check if old password matches the one in database?

I do it like this

```
  $pass_lm = md5($_POST['password_lama']); //old password
  $pass_baru = md5($_POST['password_baru']); // new password

   //check if the field is filled or not
if(isset($_POST['password_lama']) && !empty($_POST['password_lama']) 
AND isset($_POST['password_baru']) && !empty($_POST['password_baru'])){

    //check if the old password matches
    $cek=$con->query("SELECT password 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass_lm'")->num_rows;

if($cek > 0){ 
 // check if the old pass matches, it will go back to previous page and shows message
  // this is only to check if the query works as expected
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Password anda lama anda tidak benar";
    echo"<script> window.location.replace('home.php?module=editprofil') </script>";
  }
}
```

using that query, even if I input the **wrong** password, the result still TRUE, it should be FALSE since the password **does not matches** the one in database

should I post the full code?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. However you shouldn't store passwords in the database in clear text, look at using the `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions instead.

Comment: I'm asking about the correct query to check if the inputted old password matches with the one stored in databse. `md5()` is not enough?

Comment: You are also open to *myql injection*, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: md5 is terrible, modern machines can crack that pretty fast, just use the functions I mentioned they're very easy to use.

Comment: I use prepared statement. but this one is still not correct. after I found the correct one I will convert that into prepared statement

Comment: ok. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: if you do var_dump($cek) what does it show? Should ->num_rows be ->num_rows()

Comment: eh wait. if I use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, then I don't need to use `mysqli_num_rows()` ?

Comment: the real questions are: why would you want to check if the passwords match and if you're wanting to have them change/update their password? @Citra45Abadi

Comment: there is also something on Stack that you can use to change MD5 to `password_hash()` safely.

Comment: well...... I just thought about that and wanted to try to make it, just want to improve my coding skill

Answer (score 0):

Answer: none of the above.

`md5` is worse than `sha`, and you shouldn’t be using `sha` either.

PHP has built-in functionality to generate password hashes and to test passwords, and that is far superior to the old methods.

Assuming that your database stuff is OK, here is a simple code snippet to generate and test passwords.

```
//  Save Password
//  Assume $password is the original password:
    $hash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//  Now save $hash in the database
```

To test a password

```
//  Test Password
//  Assume entered password is in $password
//  Retrieve hash from database, using unique user name
    $ok=password_verify($password,$hash)
```

Note that using this method, you retrieve the hash (among other data) from the database *before* testing. Using older methods you hash the candidate and then do the retrieving.

Currently PHP uses **bcrypt** which is a relatively secure algorithm which has the additional benefit that is is deliberately slow. Not slow enough to annoy users, but slow enough to make brute force attacks much more difficult.

By using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` you ensure that PHP will use newer & better algorithms as and when they become available.

Always use the built-in PHP password functions as they are high quality and will improve and be kept up-to-date as time goes on. The exception would be if you can find a *better* mechanism, but that is for the experts.

Comment: thanks. I didn't know about this before asking this question. I will try to use it first

Comment: I have just edit my answer to give some information on the password encryption.